# Indicator vs. Indication

Tags: semantics

The Merriam Webster Dictionary gives the following definitions.

- Indicator - "one that indicates"
- Indication - "something that serves to indicate"

How are they different? Is saying that an "indicator gives an indication" correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saying that *indicator* means ‘one that indicates’ sounds as if it refers only to a person. Most of time that isn’t so. To see how well an economy is performing, we look at *economic indicators*, for example. That apart, an *indication* is indeed what an *indicator* provides. *Indicator* is the means, *indication* the result.

Answer (score 4):

They are synonyms but not really.

*Indication* means *sign* or *signal*.

> There is no indication of injury.

On the other hand, *indicator* means *measure* or the *device* which measures something. It could also be used for a person.

> The test is used as an indicator of performance.

Answer (score 4):

Indicator is something that indicates (something else) . For e.g.,

- pH indicator - it indicates the pH level
- Environmental indicator - it indicates the environmental health

Indication is what you get when you indicate something.

And yes, saying that an indicator gives an indication is *correct*.